# How do I not designate a bounty to an answer that was there prior to setting the bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063121/i-am-looking-for-documentation-or-knowledge-on-the-green-button-api) that directly pertained to my job. I asked about the Green Button API and if anyone could send me a use case. I directed the people at Green Button on their GitHub accounts to my Stack Overflow post.

They answered me in what I considered a completely unacceptable fashion, and then down-voted my question when they posted this statement:

> The websites document the use cases defined in the NAESB Energy Service Provider Interface standard. A copy of the standard is available at the [naesb.org//misc/naesb_matl_order_espi_standards.pdf] North American Energy 
>   Standards Board's website.

and I replied like so in complete and utter seriousness:

> That link is another 404 like much of the documentation I would like to look at.

I responded like so, because the API is so poorly documented and finding a use case that exists after tons of research still seemed impossible.

I then went on to set a bounty on my question which has not received any other answers, and I am expected to give it to their answer which was there prior to my bounty that did not answer me acceptably? If a bounty is set on a question after an answer is given that is not declared the right answer, why would this be the case?

Comment: Nobody forces you to assign the bounty.  Just let it expire.

Comment: Ok, I guess I was confused by the "Grace" period being this was my first bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You don't have to award a bounty:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. [...] If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

The answer in your question was posted before the bounty and doesn't reach the minimum score, so it won't receive anything if you don't want.